# Best way to rebase against a parent branch that performed a rebase?

Tags: git, rebase

I have `branch_A` that is branched off `master` and `branch_B` that is branched off `branch_A`.

```
 Master----+                       
           |                       
           |                       
           |Branch_A------+        
                          |        
                          |        
                          |Branch_B
```

In my case, `master` updated and I rebased `Branch_A`. Now `Branch_B` has diverged. The only solution I've done is make a new branch from A and cherry-pick commits. It's very convoluted and gets confusing. Is there an easier way in this current state to get `B` up to date with `A` even with the divergent history?

Answer (score 4):

```
git rebase --fork-point Branch_A
```

is your ticket, or if this is purely local work and you did `git checkout -t -b  Branch_B` while on `Branch-A` or otherwise told Git about the relationship, just plain `git rebase` will do it.

Let's do `--fork-point` by easy stages. Start where everything happens in your repo, going on the scenario in your question you did

```
git checkout -b Branch_A master
git commit however many times
git checkout -b Branch_B Branch_A
git commit however many times
git rebase master Branch_A
git commit possibly some more
git checkout Branch_B
git commit possibly even more
```

producing

```
X---*---*---*---Y    Branch_A
 \
  *---A---*---B      Branch_B
```

where `A` is the commit that was Branch_A's tip when you started `Branch_B`.  Now you want to rebase `Branch_B`. That's the situation `git rebase --fork-point Branch_A` is for.

What the `--fork-point` does is, it looks through your reflogs to see whether any of your current tip's history is really  abandoned commits from the new base's past. `X---*---A` was once `Branch_A`'s tip, Git concludes that's where you "fork"ed branch B, so that's the rebase cut point. `git rebase --fork-point Branch_A` will rebase the `A..B` range on to `Branch_A`'s current tip.

This gets much less tedious if you tell Git what you're doing. If `Branch_A` is somebody else's work you've almost certainly been fetching it, and your real base was almost certainly  `origin/Branch_A`. So `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/Branch-A Branch_B` and Git will figure it all out from just plain `git rebase`.

Comment: I think I really like the `--fork-point` idea, for this particular case. (I'm always wary of it since I'm oftentimes rebasing other dev's branches for them.) But can you elaborate on how plain `git rebase` could work here? (And also why tracking `Branch_A` helps here?) I suppose with plain rebase the old commit versions would get dropped, so it *works* in that sense, but I don't get the impression that's what you meant. ;)

Comment: Yah, if you're doing other people's rebases for them you probably want to be doing more frequent fetches to get the upstream reflogs populated, or just ask them to *send* you their reflogs.

Comment: This is great. Not sure if you explicitly need to say it, but the reason plain old `git rebase` works without any arguments is because it uses `--fork-point` by default. (That's the part I forgot.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the optional `--onto` parameter to `rebase`:

`git rebase <Branch_A-old> Branch_B --onto Branch_A`

For `<Branch_A-old>` you need either a branch or a commit ID. So, before you rebase `Branch_A` you could do something like:

```
git branch Branch_A-old Branch_A
git rebase Branch_A master
```

Or, you could simply look at the current history of Branch_B and use the *parent* commit ID of the first commit you would have cherry-picked, which will represent the previous version of the commit on `Branch_A`. Note this "fancy" rebase is doing what you did with cherry-picks, but all in one shot and without necessitating creating a new branch.

**Side Note:** you can also cherry-pick a range of commits in a single command, starting with the *parent* ID of the first commit you want to cherry-pick, through the last commit, like this:

```
git switch -c Branch_B-new Branch_A
git cherry-pick <first-commit-id>^..<Branch_B>
# note the ^ symbol refers to the parent
```

This still isn't as efficient as the single rebase command because it requires a new branch first, but it's nice to know this command exists.

**Way off to the side note:** In general, I recommend trying to avoid working on something that depends on something else that isn't merged yet, especially when you use a rebase (or squash) strategy, for the exact reasons you have witnessed. Obviously you can't avoid it all the time, and you can just `rebase --onto` when it happens. Oftentimes though, you may find you can start working on something else while you're waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. If instead of rebasing, you

```
git checkout Branch_A
git merge master
```

Fix the merge conflicts that may arise, then you can update `Branch_B` via

```
git checkout Branch_B
git merge Branch_A
```

You may still have merge conflicts and similar difficulties, but at least up to the point when `Branch_B` merged out from `Branch_A`, things are perfectly in sync between the two. So, whatever was pushed into `master` and `Branch_B` afterwards may have diverged, which means that you may need to fix this, but, if the changes are not very close to each-other in the code, then you may end up merging without conflicts.